# How to show multi-language, multi-file code blocks in webpage similar to this example in stripe docs?

Tags: javascript, html, code-snippets

At this webpage, https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#web-setup

There are examples of code snippets spread across different languages (using tabs) and different files (within same tab)

I wonder how to achieve the the same effect  and also allow copy to clipboard

See image below for what I mean

[image]

Comment: this is no easy thing to do.

You will need one <button> or <a> tag for each language, that changes the content of the div beneath. the best solution would be to create all that dynamically with js, starting from an object containing all your language, files and text. I'm working on a jsFiddle to show you what I mean

Answer (score 0):

This is quite ugly (needs more css and better javascript)
but it's a start, to give you an idea of how to proceed :

[codepen](https://codepen.io/gui3/pen/yLemWRE)

```js
let data = {
  javascript: [
    {
      filename: "javascript1.js",
      content: "//this is the content of file 1"
    },{
      filename: "file2.js",
      content: "//this is the content of file 2"
    }
  ],
  python: [
    {
      filename: "python1.py",
      content: "#this is the content of file 1"
    },{
      filename: "python2.py",
      content: "#this is the content of file 2"
    },{
      filename: "python3.py",
      content: "#this is the content of file 3"
    }
  ],
  'C++': [
    {
      filename: "c++1.cpp",
      content: "//this is the content of file 1"
    },{
      filename: "header1.h",
      content: "//this is the content of header 1"
    }
  ]
}

function clearElement(element) {
  while (element.firstChild) {
    element.removeChild(element.firstChild)
  }
}

function setupCodeBlocks(targetElementId) {
  let container = document
    .getElementById(targetElementId)
    
  clearElement(container)
    
  let languageNav = document.createElement('nav')
  
  let filesDiv = document.createElement('div')
    
  let languages = Object.keys(data)
  languages.forEach(language => {
    let languageButton = document.createElement('button')
    languageButton.id = "show:" + language
    languageButton.appendChild(
      document.createTextNode(language)
    )
    languageButton.classList.add('language')
    languageButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      show(language)
    })
    
    languageNav.appendChild(languageButton)
  })
  
  function show (language) {
    clearElement(filesDiv)
    let files = data[language]
    files.forEach(file => {
      let fileSection = document.createElement('div')
      let fileTitle = document.createElement('h3')
      fileTitle.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode(file['filename'])
      )
      let fileContent = document.createElement('textarea')
      fileContent.value = file['content']
      
      fileSection.appendChild(fileTitle)
      fileSection.appendChild(fileContent)
      filesDiv.appendChild(fileSection)
    })
  }
  
  container.appendChild(languageNav)
  container.appendChild(filesDiv)
}

setupCodeBlocks('codeblocks')
```

```css
#codeblocks {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  
}
```

```html
<h1>
 multi language/files code blocks :
</h1> 

<div id="codeblocks">
  ...loading
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve the same effect using data-id on the button and showing the div that associates with that.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse#answer-987376) for more ways to highlight for the copying part

```js
let currentID = 1;
document.getElementById("options").addEventListener("click", e => {
    if(e.target.dataset.id) {
        document.querySelectorAll(".tabs-content div").forEach(tab => {
            tab.style.display = "none";
        })
        document.querySelector(`.tabs-content [data-id="${e.target.dataset.id}"]`).style.display = "block";
        currentID = e.target.dataset.id;
    } else {
        const currentNode = document.querySelector(`.tabs-content [data-id="${currentID}"]`);
        const selection = window.getSelection();
        const range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(currentNode);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
        document.execCommand("copy");
        selection.removeAllRanges();
    }
});
```

```css
#options {
    display: flex;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

#options span {
    fill: white;
    width: 10px;
}
        
.tabs-content {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: darkblue;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <nav id="options">
      <a data-id="1">First</a>
      <a data-id="2">Second</a>
      <a data-id="3">Third</a>
      <a data-id="4">Fourth</a>
      <span>
          <svg height="15" viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="15" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="copy-btn">
              <path d="m7 5h2c1.6568542 0 3-1.34314575 3-3 1.1045695 0 2 .8954305 2 2v10c0 1.1045695-.8954305 2-2 2h-8c-1.1045695 0-2-.8954305-2-2v-10c0-1.1045695.8954305-2 2-2 0 1.65685425 1.34314575 3 3 3zm-1-3c0-1.1045695.8954305-2 2-2s2 .8954305 2 2c0 .55228475-.44771525 1-1 1h-2c-.55228475 0-1-.44771525-1-1z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
          </svg>
      </span>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="tabs-content" style="float: left;">
    <div class="code" data-id="1">
        <p>This is the first div</p>
    </div>
    <div class="code" data-id="2" style="display: none;">
        <p>This is the second div</p>
    </div>
    <div class="code" data-id="3" style="display: none;">
        <p>This is the third div</p>
    </div>
    <div class="code" data-id="4" style="display: none;">
        <p>This is the fourth div</p>
    </div>
</div>
```